# Explain random variables in analog derterministic terms

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, intuition, education

I struggle to explain discrete and continuous random variable, what it mean to integrate in terms of Ito, covariance as a measure for how much two variables jointly vary, and the like.

It would be great if there was a mental image so that one could easily transfer existing intuition in the deterministic variable to random variable. In differential geometry, for example, there is always this image of surfaces, direction and curves, which extends even to exterior and Clifford algebra.

What I am looking for is a real life intuition for the mapping from **sample space** to **measurable space**, which also maps the tools used in probability theory to something intuitive.

So far I explain it in terms of mixtures of fluids and probability densities, Fokker-Planck style.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit what level of concept you are referring to as a "real life intuition" (about measurable mapping) that can help understand Ito integral? The triplet (sample space, sigma algebra, and measurable map) certainly can be understood intuitively and be described in rather elementary terms, but the post suggests that your aim is something else.

Comment: When we study differential equations, we may want to use the tools of differential geometry to get a fuller understanding. Thus, we create a visual notion of the given equations, which helps us to guide our intuition towards the right way of approaching the problem. I'm looking for a visual image of probablitiy to guide intuition in terms of a deterministic or geometric or group-like etc aspect. Hope this clarifies it a bit better.